# Distance between center to any point on edge of rectangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems, rectangles

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/025KM.png]

As you can see in the above picture, suppose that there is a ray emitted from center which intersects the edge of the rectangle.

How do I calculate at which point the ray intersects the edge?

(So that I could be able to calculate the distance between the center and a point on the edge.)

The following is known:
    - width and height of rectangle
    - a degree & b degree (as shown in above figure)
    - centerX, centerY

Comment: more generally you have to compute the intersection of the line supporting the side ( mere to establish their equation ) with a line having a known slope ( from the angles ) and a point ( the center )

Answer (score 1):

if you only need distance then,

$$\cos b^{\circ} = {\text{half width}\over \text {distance you want to find} }$$

---

[image]

The slope of line $A$ is $0$.

let the slope of red line be $m$.

$$\tan a^{\circ} = {|0 - m| \over |1+ 0*m|} = |m|$$

you now know the slope of the red line and one point on it. Can you find the $(x2 , y2)$ now ?

Comment: half width or most generally half length of the adjacent to pointed side ?

Comment: @igael yes but it does not matter in this example.

Comment: yes, it's not important, your hints are sufficient

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:
The line intersects the top first,
or the line intersects the left first.

Using your notation,
but making $a$ and $b$
in radians,
the two distances are:

If $u$ is the distance
to the top,
$\dfrac{B}{u}
=\cos(b)
$,
so that
$u
=\dfrac{B}{\cos(b)}
$.

Similarly,
if $v$ is the distance
to the left,
$\dfrac{A}{v}
=\cos(a)
$,
so that
$v
=\dfrac{A}{\cos(a)}
$.

The distance we want
is the smaller of these,
which is
$\min\left(\dfrac{A}{\cos(a)}, 
\dfrac{B}{\cos(b)}\right)
$.

Since
$a+b
=\dfrac{\pi}{2}
$,
$\cos(b)
=\sin(a)
$,
so we can write this as
$\min\left(\dfrac{A}{\cos(a)}, 
\dfrac{B}{\sin(a)}\right)
$.

Without numerical values,
we can not decide
which value is smaller.

Comment: It can be modified as min(Math.abs(Acos(a)), Math.abs(Bsin(a)))